# Simultaneous EJB method call in the Weblogic cluster

Tags: weblogic, ejb-3.0, weblogic12c

What could be a reason of calling the `EJB method` simultaneously on the each `Weblogic node` in the `cluster`?

Currently,  I have `2 nodes` in a `cluster` and when the `Remote EJB` method(marked with the `REQUIRES_NEW` transaction attribute) has been called, it was executed on each of them - it should be executed only on one node.

The time gap between executions is only 100 microseconds. I didn't find any exception during the execution on the 1st node, so I am quite surprised why execution has been directed to the 2nd node.

Comment: Can you provide some code sample ?

Comment: There is nothing special with the code. Just casual `@Remote` method within `@Stateless` EJB Bean has been called from the Tomcat(client) via the `InitialContext.lookup`.

Comment: Have you used `stateless-bean-is-clusterable`in your `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`?

Comment: Yes, this the default setting. The surprising thing is that this occurred only once. During the normal work this method is executed only on one of the available nodes. I assume that issue could be connected with fact, that load balancing mechanism sent the execution request to the 1st node, then it noticed that this node is not accessible somehow and sent the request to the 2nd node. But there is no error found reffering to the unavailability of the 1st node in this time.